# How to make a variable from json using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

I would like to get an array with objects from json using XMLHttpRequest() and assign it to a variable.

If i log it in a console it shows the array.

```
function getData() {
  let myJson = [];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      arr = jsonData.data.children;

      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let newObject = {};
        newObject.title = arr[i].data.title;
        newObject.upvotes = arr[i].data.ups;
        newObject.score = arr[i].data.score;
        newObject.num_comments = arr[i].data.num_comments;
        newObject.created = arr[i].created_utc;
        myJson.push(newObject);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
  return myJson;
}

let data = getData();

console.log(data[0]);
```

But if I try to do anything with (console.log(data[0]);) it it returns undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any explanation! Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Just pass in the [`callback function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) instead of returning the value from an asynchronous XML HTTP request.

```js
function getData(callback) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      arr = jsonData.data.children;

      let myJson = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let newObject = {};
        newObject.title = arr[i].data.title;
        newObject.upvotes = arr[i].data.ups;
        newObject.score = arr[i].data.score;
        newObject.num_comments = arr[i].data.num_comments;
        newObject.created = arr[i].created_utc;
        myJson.push(newObject);
      }

      // Invoke the callback now with your recieved JSON object
      callback(myJson);
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}

getData(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` happens outside of the `onreadystatechange`. So you exit before you even have the data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) function to call when you have the data, or have the asynchronous call return a JS [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves with the gotten data.